# White gap between 2 rows in HTML table

Tags: html-table

I would like to give a gap between rows 2 & 3 in the below table and I would like the gap to be full white across the entire width of the table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table style="background-color:#EAEAEA">
<tr><td>lengthy text</td><td>123</td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>lengthiest text</td><td>123</td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF"><td><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>lengthier text</td><td>123</td><td>No</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code gives only the first column of the gap row in white and the other columns still show in gray (#EAEAEA)

[image: Output]

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `colspan` attribute to have your white cell be spanned over three columns:

```
<tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF"><td colspan="3"><br/></td></tr>
```

For more understanding read **[doc](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)**